# Forcing elements in the same page with HTML/CSS when saving as PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, print-css

I'm wondering, is it possible to use HTML/CSS to create a page break before an element if there is a page break in the middle of it. For example, now when i'm saving as PDF a table is split into two different pages.

Any ideas, thanks?

-Timo

Comment: I might have found a solution myself. I think that "page-break-inside : avoid" could work.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this:

```
<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
```

Here can you read more: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp 
or here:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/